# suggest npm packages for Array to excel in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, node-modules

All,

I have two simple arrays as below and want to dump the data in to excel in Nodejs. Please suggest a good npm packages for the same.

```
var Headers = ['ChangeId', 'ChangeDescription', 'ChangeDate', 'Enhancement/Fix', 'ExcutorTeam'];
var Data = ['INC1234', 'Multiple Cert cleanup', '04/07/2022', 'Enhancement', 'IlevelSupport'];
```

[image]

Comment: We have used the `node-xlsx` library. 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-xlsx

Comment: With "to dump the data into excel" you mean a simple CSV format or something complexer? If its just CSV, just join the arrays with something excel can handle as delimiter, like `,` `;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [xlsx npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx) and do something like this

This is a quick example that works, things could be improved but it will at least give you a starting point

```
const xlsx = require('xlsx');

let Headers = ['ChangeId', 'ChangeDescription', 'ChangeDate', 'Enhancement/Fix', 'ExcutorTeam'];
let Data = ['INC1234', 'Multiple Cert cleanup', '04/07/2022', 'Enhancement', 'IlevelSupport'];

let workbook = xlsx.utils.book_new();
let worksheet = xlsx.utils.aoa_to_sheet([]);

xlsx.utils.book_append_sheet(workbook, worksheet);

xlsx.utils.sheet_add_aoa(worksheet, [Headers], { origin: 'A1' });
xlsx.utils.sheet_add_aoa(worksheet, [Data], { origin: 'A2' });


xlsx.writeFile(workbook, "Test.xlsx");
```

Answer (score 0):

CSV format is just comma separated string with new lines. With that in mind we want to create a string that has the format:

```
ChangeId,ChangeDescription,ChangeDate,Enhancement/Fix,ExcutorTeam
INC1234,Multiple Cert cleanup,04/07/2022,Enhancement,IlevelSupport
```

We can iterate over Data in Headers.length sized chunks:

```js
const numColumns = Headers.length;

let file = `${Headers.join(",")}\n`;
for (let i = 0; i < Data.length; i += numColumns) {
  file += `${Data.slice(i, i + numColumns).join(",")}\n`;
}

fs.writeFileSync("file.csv", file);
```

Hope that gets you started in the right direction.

Comment: @Shivam that works. However, i have an followup question, how we handle origin value if we have multiple Data arrays from loop.